# jQuery & Backbone click events not firing

Tags: jquery, events, backbone.js

I know this problem comes up a million times, but I've been through the answers and none of them help.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZrYYy/

```
var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function () {

        console.log('Login View Intialized');
        this.el = $('#login-container');

    },

    // Setup the events (mainly the login)
    events: {

        // Login - function
        "click #login-btn" : "checkLogin"

    },

    // Actually authorization function
    checkLogin: function() {

        console.log("Authorizing login details with server...");

    }

});

// Get it all up and going
var newLogin = new Login();
var loginView = new LoginView({model: newLogin});
```

In the fiddle, when I bind a normal $('#login-btn').click(); event it works fine although it does not in my own setup (with chrome). The backbone click event does not work whatsoever.

This is what the header looks like on my own code

```
<link href="assets/admin/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="assets/admin/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="assets/admin/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="assets/admin/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/admin/backbone/login.js"></script>
<script src="assets/admin/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I know its best practice to include these in the footer but for now whilst this problem exists it doesn't matter(?).

Comment: Are there any errors in the chrome developer console?

Comment: Nope none, binding a click event from the console directly through jQuery seems to work. I've tried using .on() etc.. none of them work either. Backbone just fails..

Comment: `<script src="http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore-min.js"</script>` this is missing the `>` of the first tag

Comment: Ah that was just a formatting error, look at the fiddle thats basically what my code is.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You're setting your View element like this:

```
var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.el = $('#login-container');
  }
});
```

Every Backbone view gets a detached DOM node as its `el` upon creation. When you set `this.el` like this, Backbone is not aware that you've changed the element, and is still listening to events on the original, detached node.

Try declaring an `el` property on the view instead. This is the correct way to bind the view to a pre-existing element:

```
var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: "#login-container",
});
```

If you need to set a view's `el` dynamically during the view's lifetime, you should use `view.setElement`, which enables Backbone to bind the `events` to the new element:

```
var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.setElement($('#login-container'));
  }
});
```

**Edit based on comments:** Sounds like you're trying to initialize the view before your page is fully loaded. Backbone doesn't find the `#login-container` element, ergo doesn't bind the events. You can verify this with your fiddle too: change the `onLoad` setting to `No wrap <in head>` in the fiddle settings, and lo and behold, no events are handled.

You should only initialize your app after the DOM is ready:

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
  var newLogin = new Login();
  var loginView = new LoginView({model: newLogin});      
});
```

Or shortcut for the same:

```
$(function() {
  var newLogin = new Login();
  var loginView = new LoginView({model: newLogin});      
});
```

Comment: That works for the JSFiddle, but not for my local code.. This is getting annoying. jQuery click events don't work on local either at all, I think this is the problem?

Comment: Gah, I tried both these things separately but never together, thanks!

Comment: @SamV : Can we initialize the view in router in stead of in `document.ready` ?

Comment: @Domo I don't know, I use Angular now never got into backbone! Open a new question or google :)

Comment: The best part of learning Backbone.js in 2017 is that every problem I have has been solved by you awesome 2013 developers. Thank you, from the future.

Answer (score 5):

I had to set **el** without jQuery for it to work in JSFiddle... **el: 'body'**

Answer (score 1):

As explained by other answer, for `events` to work you need to use `el` property. `el` property is necessary to backbone on registering events by referencing the element in `el` property. But in some cases, the html is not yet generated. In those cases, you can use `tagName` instead of `el`. `tagName` is useful to generate element dynamically just like `document.createElement`.

Answer (score -1):

Backbones el Node defines the Workspace of the View Controller. Only Nodes inside el will be affected, listened or changed from Backbones render Method.

Set el as close as possible to the Area you want to maintain with your View Controller to avoid intersections or unwanted parenting with other View Controllers.

Imagine View1 includes the Area of View2 and render over its Nodes. View2 will not work any more if it holds References of Nodes, because they may be broken through the rendering from View1.

So be aware of View Intersections and its risks. Backbone is a Library, not a Framework and will not protect you from doing stupid things.